# Prove the indication in Integration

Tags: measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

Any body can help me to prove this problem in simple function?

> Let if $g_n \geq 0$, $g_n \rightarrow g$ and $\int g_n d\mu \leq E \leq \infty$ then $\int g_n d\mu \leq E$
>   with $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ as measurable function and $E\in \Sigma$.

Hope that this is will be clear, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fatou's Lemma we have that since $g_{n}\ge0$ and $g_{n}\to g$ then

$\int gd\mu\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\int g_{n}d\mu\le E$.

(I have assumed that you wanted to prove $\int gd\mu\le E$ since otherwise it follows directly from the statement of the question. Also I think you meant $E\in[0,\infty)$)